# Displaying tree structure (parent-child nodes) in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am about to start a project for android honeycomb, I am in the phase to decide about the controllers i need to display the "tree" kind of structure in my android app with nodes and sub-nodes (parent-child nodes) I need a guideline that could help me to make such thing. the children nodes of a node will appear after the press/tap on the parent node, the nodes could contain something like checkbox etc to get the user input. Ideas are welcome, yet link to some tutorial could be really helpful.

Thanks 
MGD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) might work for what you need.

I believe by default it may only support 1 level of depth. But if you need more levels there is a modified version of it online somewhere that supports as many levels as you want.